# Workaround for not being able to use calculated field in a CASE statement

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to create a field that only calculates when another calculated field is >= 100%. But when I try `CASE WHEN Performance >= 1 THEN Product Count * 20 ELSE 0` then it says **Invalid Formula**. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you cannot use a formula in a then condition. Instead you need to create a `calculated field` that contains `product count * 20`. Then you can use that field as value of the then condition.

Read more here: https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with a single [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685):

```sql
Product Count * (CASE
    WHEN Performance >= 1 THEN 20
    ELSE 0 END)
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/cab44f89-c1fb-41a6-9d68-d8c4328f942a) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]